# Clear <p:selectCheckboxMenu filter="true"> from client side

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5 `<p:selectCheckboxMenu filter="true">` and I need to reset its filter from client side. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I need to clear filter, not selection.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my solution with community:

The idea is to set empty string to filter input, and fire 'keyup' event

```
function resetFiltering(filterSelector) {
    $(filterSelector).val('').trigger('keyup');
};
```

Could be called with following selector:

```
resetFiltering('.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-container input');
```